# Gtk3 CSS background-image won't display pixel by pixel

Tags: css, background-image, gtk3

I'm working on a Gtk3 theme and cant get small background-images to display sharply. I'd like them to be displayed as they are, pixel by pixel, without scaling, anti alias etc.

To narrow down the problem I made a file ~/.themes/test/gtk-3.2/gtk.css

containing only:

```
combobox button arrow
{
    min-width:15px;
    min-height:6px;
    background-image:url("comboBoxBeam.png");
    background-size: 15px 6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

and fired up awf-gtk3 or gtk3-widget-factory. In the image below, you see screen grabs from:

1) the original comboBoxBeam.png
2) the image as displayed in awf-gtk3 app with the above gtk.css file
3) the image displayed in awf-gtk3 with this gtk.css file (height 5 instead of 6):

```
combobox button arrow
{
    min-width:15px;
    min-height:5px;
    background-image:url("comboBoxBeam.png");
    background-size: 15px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

In 2) the image is displayed with height 7 and blurry
In 3) the image is displayed sharp and in the given size, but the original size is 1 pixel larger

How do I display the image as the original is, the same, pixel by pixel?

(Xubuntu 17.10, gtk version 3.22)

[Gtk3 background-image rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZLJm.png)